# python search for files on hd and copy to usb

Tags: python, windows

I am looking for a way in python to search %systemdrive% for pdf files and copy them to my usb drive

xcopy in batch used to work

xcopy “$systemdrive%*.jpg” %~d0\%computername% /s/c/q/r/h

but wildcards in windows7 will no longer work, so looking for an alternative in python.

Comment: Consider looking into [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx), the New! Shiny! `xcopy` replacement. It might behave better on new cmd versions. Otherwise, you're looking for [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.walk) and the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3/library/shutil.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

try this, can help you:

```
import os
import shutil
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\znc\resp\A'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] == '.pdf':
            shutil.copy2(r'%s\%s' %(dirname,filename), r'D:\resp\B')
```

this works, but I do not know if it's the best

Comment: File extensions are not always 3 characters.

Rather than `filename[-4:]` do `os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]`.

Comment: sorry forgot to escape the bars

Comment: @Jace:  Extensions on filenames ending in `.pdf` are!  But I see your point -- it's one more thing to change if you want to change the extension, or if you want to make this a function of the extension.  Still, I'd suggest `filename.endswith('.pdf')` (or `'.jpg'`, which is what the OP asks for).  Also, @Marcelo, you don't have to escape your backslashes if you put `r` in front of your strings.  As in `r'C:\znc\resp\A'`.